# Retrieving event log in BlackBerry/WebWorks/PhoneGap application

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

Does anybody know how to retrieve an event log for a BlackBerry/WebWorks application?

I'm testing our Jquery Mobile/PhoneGap app in an actual device (BlackBerry Curve 9300) and I would like to use the event log (if there is one) to find and debug errors.

The app works fine in the simulator but crashes on the actual device.

Comment: What OS is the device running?

Comment: @jeffheifetz "It was running OS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to debug the javascript ob BBOS 6.0.

One possible option is to use webworks with the "-s" flag which will output the source in Java including the files necessary to import the project into the JDE or eJDE. You can then debug from there and possibly see some additional logs.